# Differences between pipeline and rising_edge in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to understand some VHDL code and I'm stuck with understanding this part:

```
...
accumulated_x <= input_x;
...
     if accumulated_x = '0' and input_x = '1' then
```

For me it is the same as:

```
if rising_edge(input_x) then
```

But when I replace it like this, it does not work and then it means it not the same, why?

Comment: You need to provide more context. It is probably relevant what hides behind the `...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rising_edge` is true for only a single infinitesimally short moment (formally, **delta cycle**).

Taking a wild guess that your two lines

```
accumulated_x <= input_x;
if accumulated_x = '0' and input_x = '1' then
```

are inside a clocked process, (as implied by the use of "pipeline" in the title, then this `if` condition will be true for an entire clock cycle.

That's the difference. What that difference means for your design is impossible to say given the information we have.

Answer (score 0):

`rising_edge` has a specific meaning to the synthesis tools. It is used to indicate that this signal is the clock for the design.

There are some good explanations [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/176708/why-rising-edge-is-only-used-to-detect-clock-input) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879960/vhdl-multiple-rising-edge-detections-inside-a-process-block) (I have included the second link as I am assuming you already have a domain clock and the synth tools are throwing errors).